# How to force disconnect status to a mapped printer on Windows?

Tags: networking, printer

I know using `NET USE LPT1 /DELETE` can "disconnect" the printer but it doesn't show as "disconnected". I need to force a mapped printer in the LPT1 to show that the printer went offline.